# Azure - Setting up storage spaces direct S2D

Tags: azure, storage, cloud-storage

I need to setup a windows cluster in Azure that uses shred storage, I have been told that I can use storage spaces direct, i have attempted to enable it but it complains that there are no suitable disks so cannot set it up, none of the guides online appear to work.
How do I setup storage spaces direct on Azure 2016 data center server as it appears to want iSCSI disks?

Comment: When you say "shared storage", do you absolutely need iSCSI? Will just CSV or just SMB3 work? Who's your shared storage consumer?

Comment: I wish to set up a cluttered resource in azure using windows cluster failover and present that clustered service with storage, windows requires it to be of a certain type but azure is limited to the types it can provide

Comment: Again, who's your shared storage consumer? Is it a hard requirement to have iSCSI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly speaking, I wouldnt rely on MSFT iSCSI Target failover due to its poor performance (no caching, active-passive scenario etc).

Especially, there is a much easier and time-tested way to create a shared storage in Azure:

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/starwind.starwindvirtualsan

**What you need:** just a pair of Windows VMs which you can consider as cluster nodes and where you can enable StarWind vSAN.

**What you get:** a fault tolerant cluster with a highly-available shared storage attached meaning that each VM contains a consistent copy of data. Furthermore, Starwind gives you a fully compatible and high-performance iSCSI stack and also the possibility to levereage RDMA protocol suite by supporting iSER.